# How to decide whether the journal is pure or applied?

Tags: soft-question

I am a beginner in research and have draft ready for my first article.  I have a little confusion about the pure and applied journal in Mathematics.   My work belongs to pure mathematics(I think). And wanting to send to the following journal:
[Applied and Computational Harmonic Analysis](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/journaldoc.html?cn=Appl_Comput_Harmon_Anal).

But my confusion is whether the above journal is pure or applied ? Or both ? Whether it has good prestige in pure mathematics ?

Any of your suggestions would be appreciated,
 Thanks,

Comment: According to the (now discontinued) Australian Research Council journal list, this is an A* (top bracket) journal that falls under both Pure Maths and Applied Maths.

Comment: According to the Finnish publication forum journal classification, this is a rank 2 journal (3 is best and rare, 1 is worse, 0 is non-scientific) and the fields are mathematics, physics and applied mathematics (in no particular order). For details, click the journal name at the bottom of this page: http://www.tsv.fi/julkaisufoorumi/haku.php?nimeke=Applied+and+computational+harmonic+analysis&konferenssilyh=&issn=&tyyppi=kaikki&kieli=&maa=&wos=&scopus=&nappi=Search It seems to me that the journal is *both* pure and applied and has good prestige.

Comment: A look at the editorial board shows some eminent and strong mathematicians whose work gets classified as "pure maths"

Comment: Just a short comment: there is this Science Citation Report, published every year. One can find the impact factor and article influence score etc. Usually, if the journal accepts low number of papers and has high article influence score, then it has good reputation.

Answer (score 4):

For a beginning mathematician, the best advice is to follow the adviser's recommendation in the journal choice. Considering the reputation of a journal, there are many ratings, for example, Mathscinet journal citation database. Another advise, look what kind of papers are published there. Look where the people you cite publish their papers. If the journal is not in your library, this is an indication of the too high price, and you probably do not want to publish in such a journal.